# Interfacing with PowerPoint presentations

Tags: c#, .net, window, powerpoint, office-interop

I want to be able to send signals to a PowerPoint presentation (running) in order to programmatically tell the presentation when to move to the next slide.

#### Technology constraints

Almost none. I am evaluating my options here. Of course it would be nice to have API in C#, but if COM is inevitable then so be it as well as some other crazy API like VBA and so on!

#### Scenarios

No limits here as well. Just a running PowerPoint presentation and want to send an event so that it moves to the next slide! If this involves running another process, a service, whatever, fine!

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few ways, I am not going to do all the work for you but you could do something like this.

Powershell & PSexec on command PC

```
Start-Process $pse -ArgumentList "\\$asset Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command {$wshShell = new-object -com wscript.shell;$wshShell.SendKeys("{RIGHT}"}"
```

Remote PC has PSExec open in background and start powershell pressing the Right arrow key once.

Basically this a code snip from a similar piece of work that would max out the volume on a target machine. I have modified it to match your requirements but its un-tested, you will probably need to play with it.

If all of this is taking place locally then its even easier. You just simulate the keyboard actions in your chosen language, Powershell, C#, etc.

Comment: Ok, so basically your approach is using keyboard events, no real IPC with PowerPoint. Fair enough, sounds like something to try out :)

Comment: Its the simplest way I can think of doing it or like you say, check out the powerpoint com object. I am pretty sure key strokes are how the usb wireless presenters work.